# mysql database connects only if i run my local wamp server even though all the files are in server site

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-connection, web-hosting

Its not connecting to my web hosting server database even though all the files are in server and all the credentials( username, password, database and host-name ) are updated! why its still connecting to my local machine database? even though i changed the username and password, its connecting to my local database itself! how's that possible?
I created another new database and tables in my server database. everything is done! but connecting to my local database!!

```
<?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

 define('DB_NAME', 'asknow');
 define('DB_USER', 'myself');
 define('DB_PASSWORD', '*****');
 define('DB_HOST', '134.345.**');

$dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

?>
```

Comment: That is _not_ possible, sorry. You probably are looking at an issue with how you interpret what you see.

Comment: this connection file is on remote sever?If yes then it will never connect with your local machine.

Comment: what do you mean by `server` here? third-party server?

Comment: Yeah, its on third party server. for ex: when i submit form to my website it doesn't work. but when i run wamp server in my local machine then try to submit the form in my website it's sending all the data to my local database itself! not on my web hosting server!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you set your host as localhost, which means your computer here.

```
define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
```

That is why your data still goes to your local database.

Instead, you should set your database's ip on your shared hosting as your host.

---- Edited ---- (because the question is edited)

You should use your dns like `www.yourdns/connect.php` to link to your connect.php file in your shared hosting.

Comment: i did that, but still the same problem. It's executing file connect.php that is located in my c:/wamp folder. instead of executing connect.php in third party server.

Comment: @Karthiksamyak eh then i guess u showed us wrong piece of code. You should show us how you include the connect.php in your shared hosting. You should use your dns like `www.yourdns/connect.php` to link to your connect.php file in your shared hosting.

Comment: thanks for your time and response. It took me 3 hours of exausted testing to find the error!....The problem is with the ajax request url, where i forgot to change it to web server address.